# Drawing an open arc with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to draw an **open** arc with three.js using the code from an example in three.js docs.

The problem with this code is that it draws a straight line from the end point of the arc back to its starting point. I wonder if there is a way to draw an open arc.

I have tried various methods on `THREE.Path`, like `THREE.Path.ellipse`, but they all seem to do the same thing.

```
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
  0, 0,             // ax, aY
  7, 15,            // xRadius, yRadius
  0, 3/2 * Math.PI, // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
  false             // aClockwise
);
var path = new THREE.Path(curve.getPoints(50));
var geometry = path.createPointsGeometry(50);
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
var ellipse = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
this.scene.add(ellipse);
```

Comment: You'll be more likely to get help if you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an open arc (or line) in three.js, you can use a pattern like so:

```
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
    0, 0,             // ax, aY
    7, 15,            // xRadius, yRadius
    0, 3/2 * Math.PI, // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
    false             // aClockwise
);

var points = curve.getSpacedPoints( 20 );

var path = new THREE.Path();
var geometry = path.createGeometry( points );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

scene.add( line );
```

three.js r.71

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but THREE.RingGeometry would be a good solution.

Just use the thetaLength argument to tweak the curve length.
Although you are actually drawing a section of a ring instead of a true arc, you can add thickness very easily.

Check out the documentation and an interactive demo here:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/RingGeometry